# How can aspect-ratio-preservation + centering-in-div be simultaneously satisfied for an img element?

Tags: css, svg

This [example](http://phrogz.net/svg/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml) from phrogz.net shows how to render an SVG element on either a page of aspect ratio close to 1:2 or 2:1. Either way the SVG appears at 1:1 ratio.

[image: preserve SVG aspect ratio]

How can the same aspect-ratio-preservation + centering-in-div be simultaneously satisfied for an img element?

[image: skewed image]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n54m6Ls8/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html > 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Sizing SVG & IMG to Fill a Container</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            html, body { background:#eee; margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }
            #foo { position:absolute; left:2%; width:46%; top:2%; height:96%; background:red; }
            #bar { position:absolute; left:52%; width:46%; top:2%; height:96%; background:grey; }

            svg { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:green; }
            img { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:green; }

            .face { stroke:#000; stroke-width:20px; stroke-linecap:round }
        </style>
    </head><body>
        <div id="foo">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" viewBox="-350 -250 700 500">
            <circle r="200" class="face" fill="yellow"/>
                <path fill="none" class="face"
                      transform="translate(-396,-230)"
                      d="M487.41,282.411c-15.07,36.137-50.735,61.537-92.333,61.537 c-41.421,0-76.961-25.185-92.142-61.076" />
                <circle cx="-60" cy="-50" r="20" fill="#000"/>
                <circle cx="60" cy="-50" r="20" fill="#000"/>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div id="bar">
            <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/196201/Model-T-Ford.png&disposition=attachment" />
        </div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Centering

Add `position:relative` to `#bar` then add the following to `<img>`:

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3D(-50%, -50%, 0);
```

#### Maintain AR

Give absolute dimensions to `<img>` (used `min-width` and `min-height`) and add this to `<img>`:

```
object-fit:contain;
```

Here's the modified [<kbd>**FIDDLE**</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/oky4gLpw/) The dimensions for the `<img>` and `#bar` are scaled back to 10% so it is on par with the SVG. Note there is no comparison between SVG and `<img>` in Snippet, but the code for the `<img>` is the same with the exception of the scaled dimensions.

#### SNIPPET

```css
#bar {
  min-width:208px;
  min-height: 320px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 245px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3D(-50%, -50%, 0);
  object-fit: contain;
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">
  <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/196201/Model-T-Ford.png&disposition=attachment" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you set you image as css style you can do it

```css
html, body { background:#eee; margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }
#foo { position:absolute; left:2%; width:46%; top:2%; height:96%; background:red; }
#bar { 
  background: url(http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Car-Download-PNG.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  position:absolute; left:52%; width:46%; top:2%; height:96%; }

svg { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:green; }
img { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:green; }

.face { stroke:#000; stroke-width:20px; stroke-linecap:round }
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" viewBox="-350 -250 700 500">
    <circle r="200" class="face" fill="yellow"/>
    <path fill="none" class="face"
          transform="translate(-396,-230)"
          d="M487.41,282.411c-15.07,36.137-50.735,61.537-92.333,61.537 c-41.421,0-76.961-25.185-92.142-61.076" />
    <circle cx="-60" cy="-50" r="20" fill="#000"/>
    <circle cx="60" cy="-50" r="20" fill="#000"/>
  </svg>
</div>
<div id="bar">
</div>
```